# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/firebase_firestore.js?v=32c7ddf6' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I'm trying to use firebase in my Vue app but it's giving the above-mentioned error. The firebase init file is as follows.

```
**import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import firestore from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx",
  appId: "xxx",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebaseApp.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });
// firebase.analytics();

// export firestore database
export default firebaseApp.firestore();**
```

I have installed firebase 8.0.0 in the app.

Comment: Can you share your package.json? and the file where you are importing the Firestore instance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: this is the package.json  {
  "name": "smoothies-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 5050"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.6.10",
    "slugify": "^1.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.2.31",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.2.2",
    "vite": "^2.8.4"
  }
}

Comment: @Dharmaraj
 thanks for the concern but I have found the solution and resolved the error

Comment: how you fixed? @RanaWaqarAhmad

Answer (score 2):

Try this since it got updated to web version 9,

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
 ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


// Initialize Cloud Firestore and get a reference to the service
const db = getFirestore(app);
```